# Specifying a domain of a cube without corners in Matlab using a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, boundary

I would like to specify the domain in Matlab as attached below. This turned out to be harder than I thought. So far, I tried two types of approaches:

1. **The small to large approach.** Here, I start with defining the cube in the middle and then add the 6 blocks that are sticking out. So I end up with 7 domains, for each of which I specify the main equations and the boundary conditions. This seems to work, but is obviously very slow. I prefer a solution more like 2, which is:
2. **The large to small approach.** Here, I start with a cube that is bigger than the actual domain and I want to tell Matlab which parts to exclude from the domain, e.g. the parts in the corners. Suppose the corners are from i/j/k==1 to i/j/k==2. And here, I am not sure how to do this. Concretely, what happens is that if either of the three coordinates is 1 or nx/ny/nz, the range of the other two coordinates should be 2:(nx/ny/nz-1).

In logical terms, this second approach would look like:

```
for i=1:nx
for j=1:ny
for k=1:nz

%x
if (j==1||j==ny) for i=2:(nx-1)
elseif (k==1||k==nz) for i=2:(nx-1)
else for i=1:nx
end

%y
if (i==1||i==nx)for j=2:(ny-b1)
elseif (k==1||k==nz)for j=2:(ny-1) 
else  for j=1:ny
end

%z
if (i==1||i==nx) for k=2:(nz-1)
elseif (j==1||j==ny) for k=2:(nz-1)
else for k=1:nz
end
```

I know this is no valid Matlab syntax because of the *for* after the *if*-statement, but this is to give a clear idea of what I want. My question is, is there another way to write this such that it does work in Matlab?!

Alternatively, I was thinking about something like:

```
for i=1:((nx/3))
for j=1:ny
for k=1:nz

if(i==(2||(nx-2))&&(k==1||k==nz ||j==1||j==ny))  ux(i,j,k)=BC1;
elseif(i==1&&k~=1&&k~=nz&&j~=1&&j~=ny) ux(i,j,k)=BC2;
elseif(i==1) ux(i,j,k)=0; %here also u and uxx need to be set 0. 
else definition ux
end
```

The problem with this is that you still have to specify i==1 at the corners, e.g. instead of excluding the corners from the domain, you include the corners and set all corner-related values at 0. I prefer really to exclude them.

None of these methods works well and I am wondering if there isnt any better and more straightforward method?

[Picture of the domain to be described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0GMJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to prepare a binary mask of the edges, if you're matrix name is `m`:

```
mask=zeros(size(m));
mask(1,:,end)=1;
mask(end,:,1)=1;
mask(1,:,1)=1;
mask(end,:,end)=1;
mask(:,1,1)=1;
mask(:,1,end)=1;
mask(:,end,1)=1;
mask(:,end,end)=1;
mask(1,1,:)=1;
mask(1,end,:)=1;
mask(end,1,:)=1;
mask(end,end,:)=1;
```

then:

```
m.*~mask
```

will get you want you wanted...

[image: using blockPlot from fex, with 7x9x11 matrix]

this figure was created using `blockPlot` from fex, with `m=ones(7,9,11);`